# Given an array of strings varying in length, how can I replace every string with the same word

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, gsub

I have to replace a number of strings with the same word, lets say that word is "plum".

An example could be...
"This is a string" and expected output would be "plum plum plum plum" or
"I'm happy" output "plum plum"

So far I have converted the string into an array, mapped and counted using...

```
string = sentence.split(&:map).to_a
n = string.count.to_i
```

I am now trying to replace each string in the array using `sentence.gsub[0..n]` which I expected to replace each position in the array with my word.

I'm sure this is not the best way to do this, however I would really appreciate help on this particular method to help my understanding of where I've gone wrong in my thinking as well as finding out that I could have done it with far cleaner code

Comment: please, write instances

Comment: Provide an example input and your expected output.

Comment: Sorry about that, have added

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your effort toward solving the question, which the code you show doesn't do. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Without your actual attempt and an explanation of why it does do what you want it looks like you barely tried and gave up and want us to write it for you. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is applicable.

Comment: Apologies, I will read the "how to ask" and others that you've recommended. It may look like I barely tried here but in my question I did ask that someone could point me in the direction of where I was going wrong with my code rather than give me the simplest way. I'm grateful to those who helped me but I still don't understand why I couldn't sub each section after I had got to the problem above. Perhaps I need to find a different site that doesn't mock beginners who can't find the particular problems they're looking for online

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
"This is a string".split.map { "plum" }.join(" ")
=> "plum plum plum plum"
```

Or by using `gsub`:

```
"This is a string".gsub(/[^\s]+/, "plum")
=> "plum plum plum plum"
```

Comment: Thank you, that has done it. May I ask what the relevance of the e inside the || is if any?

Comment: e is a block parameter.  In this case it's not strictly necessary and could be replaced with `_`

Comment: @mcfinnigan, it can be omitted)

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with it a little to make sure I understand fully. I've had a few problems trying to use blocks so it's usually not my first thought

Answer (score 0):

You can just repeat "plum" as many times as you have words...

```
sentence = "This is a string"
("plum " * sentence.split.count).strip
=> "plum plum plum plum"
```